# Edit button in GridView isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My page first displays a dropdown menu of events. A user selects an event from this dropdown menu and clicks a button. After the button is clicked, a GridView is filled with the corresponding data. This all works fine.

Then as the user views this data, there are two buttons that are available: edit and delete. Clicking on edit should allow the user to edit the row right there. Then the edit button turns into an update button, which they will then click to update the row. This is the area that doesn't work.

Right now, everything is fine up until the person clicks edit. When they click edit, the program either crashes or clears the GridView. I know something is wrong with my code... I think it has to do with `BindGrid()` (see in my C#). Can anyone help me with this?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin/admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="copycopyviewregistrant.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_Default5" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    Choose event:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListEvent" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonChangeEvent" runat="server" 
        onclick="ButtonChangeEvent_Click" Text="Button" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RegistrantId"
OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit"
OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" 
        EmptyDataText="No records has been added." CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="PagingRegistrant_PageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" ItemStyle-Width="80">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" ItemStyle-Width="80">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>

        <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address Line 1" ItemStyle-Width="80">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAddressLine1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AddressLine1") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressLine1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AddressLine1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" 
        ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="150">
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:CommandField>
</Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;


public partial class admin_Default5 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string events = DropDownListEvent.SelectedValue;

            using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConn2.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
                    sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                    sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd2.CommandText = "spGetAllEvents";

                    sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader();

                    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        DropDownListEvent.DataSource = sqlReader;
                        DropDownListEvent.DataTextField = "EventName";
                        DropDownListEvent.DataValueField = "EventId";
                        DropDownListEvent.DataBind();
                    }

                    sqlConn2.Close();
                }

            }

        }
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegistrantsGridView"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT");
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                        this.BindGrid();
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

    //Edit Button
    protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }

    //Update Button
    protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int registrantId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        string firstName = (row.FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox).Text;
        string lastName = (row.FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox).Text;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegistrantsGridView"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "UPDATE");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrantId", registrantId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine1", addressLine1);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine2", addressLine2);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", state);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", zip);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", country);


                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();
    }

    //Cancel Edit Button
    protected void OnRowCancelingEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();
    }

    //Delete Button
    protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int registrantId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegistrantsGridView"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "DELETE");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrantId", registrantId);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        this.BindGrid();
    }

    //JavaScript confirm delete
    //protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex != GridView1.EditIndex)
    //    {
    //        (e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[2] as LinkButton).Attributes["onclick"] = "return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');";
    //    }
    //}

    protected void PagingRegistrant_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
       GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; 
        DataBind();
    }
    protected void ButtonChangeEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegistrantsGridView"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownListEvent.SelectedValue;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just apply a `breakpoint` at `OnRowEditing` event and see it there's any exception that is being raised. I guess there must have been an `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

Comment: @Suprabhat I tried this and no error came back.

Comment: @Satinder Thanks I will look at this.